# Use LVGL on frame buffer in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, framebuffer

Trying to run LVGL application on frame buffer in TTY console in Ubuntu system that runs on VmWare virtual machine. Ubuntu runs desktop, but I need to test frame buffer. Can't make mouse work in my application.
I found that mouse is on `/dev/input/event2` with help of `sudo evtest /dev/input/eventX`.
I run application as root since Ubuntu asks for root permission to access frame buffer.
I have defined EVDEV and frame buffer:

```
/*-----------------------------------------
 *  Linux frame buffer device (/dev/fbx)
 *-----------------------------------------*/
#ifndef USE_FBDEV
#  define USE_FBDEV           1
#endif

#if USE_FBDEV
#  define FBDEV_PATH          "/dev/fb0"
#endif
.....
/*-------------------------------------------------
 * Mouse or touchpad as evdev interface (for Linux based systems)
 *------------------------------------------------*/
#ifndef USE_EVDEV
#  define USE_EVDEV           1
#endif

#if USE_EVDEV
#  define EVDEV_NAME   "/dev/input/event2"
```

But mouse is not working on my application.
I also got blinking cursor which is not nice and I would like to remove it.
How to solve these problems?

Comment: Wouldn't C flag be more suitable than C++?

Comment: Any relevance? https://forum.lvgl.io/t/evdev-mouse-not-working/562/3